# SIP API media codecs

Tags: android, sip, codec

I am trying to develop an android application with SIP API (provided in Android 2.3 or higher). I want to know which audio codecs and video codecs does this API supports ? does this API have any tools allowing to configure/choose codecs ? please help me.

Comment: Interesting i am not sure if you will be able to do audio and video call with existing android sip software stack

Comment: @AbhijitChakra: this can assure you: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip.html

Comment: This not working try that demo app..

Comment: @AbhijitChakra: are you sure ? maybe your device does not support VoIP communication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to know which audio codecs and video codecs does this API supports?

You can get supported codec list from docs itself, check [AudioCodec](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/rtp/AudioCodec.html).

Those are:

- PCMU
- PCMA
- GSM_EFR
- GSM
- AMR

> does this API have any tools allowing to configure/choose codecs ?

you could use the APIs related to the SIP and RTP.  `android.net.rtp` contains the `AudioStream`, `AudioGroup` and `AudioCodec` classes that are easy to use. The last of these allows you to choose the codec which you want.

You can create codec as given in above link:

```
AudioCodec codec = AudioCodec.getCodec(100, "AMR/8000", "mode-set=1");
```

Then you can set this codec to your [AudioStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/rtp/AudioStream.html) using `setCodec(codec)` method.

Comment: thanks a lot! do you think there is a class in android.net.sip that takes this AudioCodec as argument. I am new in this domain

Comment: I have edited my answer to give your brief. This should get you started. Hope it covers major aspects of your question

Comment: Hi. I'm having trouble with my sip calling. The call is registered and established, but there is no sound. I'm thinking it could be because of codecs. How do I actually set which codec my sip call should use?