# Android SIP audio call : How disable noise suppression?

Tags: android, audio, sip, noise-reduction

I have implemented [native Android SIP solution](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip.html) in my Android app.

```
SipProfile.Builder builder = new SipProfile.Builder("username", "host");
builder.setPassword("password");
SipProfile me = builder.build();

//open
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("android.truc.INCOMING_CALL");
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
manager.open(me, pendingIntent, null);

//make sip call
manager.makeAudioCall(me.getUriString(), "sip:username:host", new SipAudioCall.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void onCallEstablished(SipAudioCall call) {
        call.startAudio();
    }
}, 5);
```

All work fine, I can call another SIP client.
But I want listen background sound and I feel there is a noise suppression, because I don't listen background sound.

There is noise suppression in native Android SIP library ?
How can disable this noise suppression with native Android SIP library ?
Or how increase the volume of microphone ?

Comment: have you checked [AudioEffect](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/AudioEffect.html) - [NoiseSuppressor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/NoiseSuppressor.html)

Comment: @user2450263 : Yes I checked, I not find anything !... I find no interaction between SipAudioCall and NoiseSuppressor...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some research on the source code implementations of SIPAudioCall and Manager classes, I found the only thing that could be causing the noise suppression would be the audio codec modules.

Doing some more research on these codecs I found that lots of these codecs like [AMR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_Multi-Rate_Wideband) actively used in VOIP provide noise suppression. If what you are looking for is no noise suppression you will need to find which codec does not provide noise suppression or play around with different codecs available. To manipulate the codec used please refer to this answer [manipulate codecs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36915903/sip-api-media-codecs?rq=1).
Also a [list](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6242/what-codecs-does-the-2-3-gingerbread-internet-calling-sip-use) of codecs used in android VOIP.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your idea ! But I search since this morning, impossible to find an code sample of SIP native + custom codec.